# How to convert this code of date to swift?

Tags: swift, xcode6

I have this code in Objective-C:

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"];
NSString* dateTimePrefix = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

I'm trying to convert to Swift, but I  don't know any lines this is my try:

```
var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"
var dateTimePrefix : NSString
dateTimePrefix = formatter.stringFromDate(formatter as? NSData)
```

I get errors in `stringFromDate`. What is the problem?

Comment: where did you get that `[NSDate date]` would be equal to this `formatter as? NSData` in _Swift_? the second code would be euqal to something like this in _ObjC_: `[formatter isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]?formatter:nil`, which is definitely not the same as `[NSDate date]` on any levels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

that would be the same code in *Swift*:

```
var formatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"
let dateTimePrefix: String = formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
```

Answer (score 2):

## Disclamer

By analyzing your question and your code it seems you don't try to understand what you are doing. Try to read the methods documentation and be aware of types it requires.

## Error

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/stringFromDate:) `stringFromDate` takes a `NSDate` as input.

You give it an `NSDateFormatter` tried to be casted as `NSData`.

The original code `[NSDate date]` just create a new NSDate instance (which is the current date). You should read the [Swift initialization documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Initialization.html) to be confortable with it.

## Answer

Replace

```
formatter.stringFromDate(formatter as? NSData)
```

with

```
formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
```

Answer (score 0):

With Swift 5, you can use `DateFormatter`'s [`string(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1415810-string) method in order to convert a `Date` into a formatted `String`.

The following Playground sample code show how to use `string(from:)`:

```
import Foundation

let date = Date()

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"

let dateString = formatter.string(from: date)
print(dateString) // prints: 2019-03-04-17-59-23
```